# Can SailsJS use existing mongo data with string _id fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Can SailsJS mongo adapter (sails-mongo) use existing mongo data (not created via SailsJS) with string _id fields (as opposed to ObjectIds)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You just need to set the `autoPK` setting to `false` in your model:

```
module.exports = {

    autoPK: false,
    attributes: {...},
    ...

}
```

See the full docs [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#options).

Comment: In fact i didn't need to, new records are still created with ObjectIDs, old ones are treated normally (until proven otherwise) with their string IDs!
I'm proceeding with this and will answer my question when it's been tested thoroughly..